# How can I fix the internal error in Django?

Tags: django, docker

I don't have a lot of experience in Django and I am a fairly green developer. When I run the localhost I keep getting a Internal Error. I have tried most of the solutions to similar problems here and none of them works. Can anyone help me? The code is not mine so I don't want to alter it as such either.

Here is a picture of the errors I keep getting:

[image: Error Page]

Comment: Don't post errors as images. Copy/Paste it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do without altering the code is to enter the value "shop_all_art" in the HomePage table in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Do not share code via images. You should also share the related code.

Your stacktrace clearly says, that Python is not able to access first element of `HomePage.objects.filter(value='shop_all_art')` in file `bidgala/bidgala/pages/views.py`. `all_art_img` is most probably empty.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `all_art_img` is empty.

you should check if a Query has any elements before with a method such as

```
if all_art_img.exists():
    all_art_img[0]
```